# Do Group Declarations Cause ByRef Compile Errors?

Tags: vba, excel

I am scripting in Excel 2016 and came across some strange behaviour depending on how I define my variables. I created some example code below to reproduce the error.

I would like to know if this is a known VBA bug or if I am doing something wrong?

```
Sub IWork()
  Dim name As String  ' name is declared alone
  Dim lastname As String
  name = "Ben"
  Hello name:=name
End Sub

' IFail creates a compile error
' ByRef argument type mismatch
Sub IFail()
  Dim name, lastname As String  ' name is declared with other variables
  name = "Ben"
  Hello name:=name
End Sub

Sub Hello(ByRef name As String)
' Do something with name ...
  Debug.Print "Hello " & name
End Sub
```

Comment: Not a bug. Working as designed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When  you define them like this:

```
Dim name, lastname As String
```

What you are actually defining them like is this:

```
Dim name As Variant, lastname As String
```

You want to define them like this instead

```
Dim name As String, lastname As String
```

Personally, I prefer to define them on separate lines.

```
Dim name As String
Dim lastname As String
```

And in addition, I like to prefix my variable names with a letter that reminds me what type of variable it is, and prevent confusing variable names with key words like `Name` - like this:

```
Dim sName As String
Dim sLastname As String
```

But that's just my preference.